# Recover sql database files without using sql server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

My Ubuntu computer HD crashed, so I cant boot up anymore, I'm trying to recover my data from the hard drive by booting up using the live CD.

I can access the crashed internal hard drive by mounting it from the live CD/USB.

I have a database I want to recover, but I cant start the mysql server since I boot from the live CD, mysql server wont start, so I cant use the regular mysql command line commands to do anything.

To let you know I created the data base and was using it with wordpress.

Its really urgent because I spent over 4 months entering all this data then this stupid computer crashed, I know I should have backed it up.

I dont even know which files are the database files, which file extensions to search for, or where the files are located on the ubuntu.

Does anybody know where the data base files are located, and which files to copy in order to get it back after I re-install ubuntu?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you not run chroot and then mysqldump?

Comment: @MichaelBailey In this case, you may need to mount other filesystems below old OS mountpoint, including */proc*, */dev*, which complicates the matter. Also, restoring from SQL dump takes some time for large databases. Copying binary files seems a better solution here.

Comment: Probably is better. Just an alternative if nothing else. I've never had to mount anything other than the HD itself though...

Comment: Agree on the "dump will take a while" point though

Answer (score 1):

Default path to MySQL database files in Ubuntu is */var/lib/mysql/*. If it's been modified (or installed other than from official Ubuntu package), check for *datadir* in */etc/mysql/my.cnf* or service startup script.

When you reinstall your OS with MySQL, simply replace new data directory with the old one (with *mysql* service stopped, of course). Remember about correct permissions - set *mysql*:*mysql* and *0700* or similar secure. You can use *tar* to archive the old one, so it will take care of all the permissions.